# parse through Json list and append

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, loops, append

I have been trying to basically create a div for each row of the json list returned via ajax which would append to the main div #chatcontents. However, i am facing problems with the correct syntax. I think the error is how my json is being returned.

This is the function which does the ajax call in the index.php

```
function returnValue()
{
 $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            url: "thread.php",
            data: {lastposted : dateposted},

            success: function (json) {
                if(json)
                {
                for (var i = 0, len = json.length; i < len; ++i) {
                var results = json[i];
                var newDiv = $("<div>" + results.1 + results.2  "</div>");
                }

                   $('#chatContents').append(newDiv);             
                }
            }  
        });
}
```

thread.php returns a Json result like this..

```
[{"0":"something","1":"41234","2":"test"},
{"0":"somethingmore","1":"2131","2":"test2"}]
```

The codes i have seen online seem to return the key but mine are in numberics (0,1,2). I think its coz of the way i have the returned the array. It is a 2d array which was converted to JSON. I am not sure if this is causing the problem as to how i loop through the array in the first page. Any help would be appreciated.

For a clearer pic:
thread.php has this code:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="3">
<?php
$latestmsgs = retrieveNewMsgs($lastpost,$currtime);
  ?>

 <?php echo json_encode($latestmsgs);?>
```

So basically, thread.php is refreshing every 3 seconds. Index.php makes an ajax call to this page and retrieves the latest msg in the form of json and appends.

I hope its clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `results.1` is invalid syntax, you should use `results[1]`.

**EDIT**

1. You have syntax errors on this line (apart from the bracket syntax instead of dots, you are missing a plus sign):

   ```
   var newDiv = $("<div>" + results.1 + results.2  "</div>");
   ```

   It should be

   ```
   var newDiv = $("<div>" + results[1] + results[2] + "</div>");
   ```
2. Make sure your callback is getting a *parsed* JSON object, not a raw JSON string. Alert `typeof json` inside the callback, it should say "object". If it says "string", add `dataType: 'json'` to the options object passed to `$.ajax`, and/or make sure the server is setting the proper content-type for the response.
3. Once you fix that, your code should work. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DSZuC/).

**EDIT 2**

1. The line with `.append` should be inside of your `for` loop, otherwise only the last result on the JSON will be appended to the div. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DSZuC/1/).
2. You said on the comments: "I am appending to a class="container" div". But your code says you're appending to a div with ID == "chatContents". Do you have such div?
3. When you say an alert stopped working, it means there is probably some error before the alert preventing the rest of the script to execute. Check Firebug's console for errors, and double-check all code before the alert.

Comment: actually it should be results['1']

Comment: ah yeah, .1 syntax looks funky to me though which is why I thought...nvm. Go with what works

Comment: I corrected the syntax error before testing again. But it wasnt working. I have also added the dataType:'json' and added var results = JSON.parse(json[i]); to overcome the parsing prob as suggested. But i am still not seeing any results. Oh extra information: I am appending to a class="container" div.

Comment: If you added both, you're probably double parsing, and that won't work. Are you sure your ajax call is actually returning what you expect? Test it with Firebug, and look at the console.

Comment: I tested with Firebug as suggested and just realised that <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="300"> is being returned as well! How do i return only the json without this one line. because the entire page is only refreshing and returning the updated json results. Apologies for the mistake

Comment: The PHP script is requested through Ajax must retorn the JSON only. No div, no nothing. It should contain the logic to fetch the data from the database and a single `echo` statement to output the JSON. And nothing outside the PHP opening/closing tags (`<?php ?>`).

Comment: thread.php retrieves the php array based on the parameters sent through ajax. the php array is converted to json using the following code: <div class = "jsonresults">
 <?php echo json_encode($latestresults);?>
 </div> So i need to only the contents from this div from thread.php. I hope i am not getting the concept wrong.

Comment: You are getting it wrong. You don't "get the contents of the div" with PHP. You are adding the div with PHP, just remove the div code!

Comment: I get what you mean. Considering that i have stated that the datatype returned should be only json, it should only pick up the json array. However, i need to keep refreshing the page which would only work if i use <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="300"> this code. Am i correct in presuming that i would then need to put code in php as well using echo?

Comment: You can't do that. If you need to keep refreshing, you have to setup a timer to issue new ajax requests from time to time. And a tip on PHP/JSON: I don't know what you are doing, but you can assemble the data as a regular PHP array, then just `echo json_encode($my_array)` to output it as JSON.

Comment: my entire thread.php is doing that only. I have like 2 lines in this page. <?php $latestmsgs = retrieveNewmsgs($lastpost,$currtime);
  ?>
 
 <?php echo json_encode($latestmsgs);?>

Comment: You have to remove `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="3">` from the top of thread.php.

Comment: Set up a timer in javascript to keep calling your `returnValue` function, like this: `setInterval(returnValue, 10000); // refresh every 10 secs`. If still in doubt, you should create a new question for this specific topic. There is no way your `<meta>` tag approach works with ajax. Loading content with ajax is not like loading on a regular browser window, the `<div>` cannot keep refreshing by itself because of the meta tag -- it's a div, not a window.

Comment: I forgot to update this thread. I found out the error that i was facing, and it was solved. I had already set up the timer and was still facing this problem, then realised that it was null pointer exception in the array return that was causing it to loop back to 0 making me think it wasnt refreshing. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Your thread.php is returning an array of JSON strings...you need to loop the array and then parse each string in order to get the object.

```
for (var i = 0, len = json.length; i < len; ++i) {
  var results = JSON.parse(json[i]);
  var newDiv = $("<div>" + results['1'] + results['2']  "</div>");
}
```